# Click mat-card-title to then display the mat-card-content?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a super basic angular project. As of now, there exists the mat-card-title and then the mat-card-content. I would like it so that the mat-card-content will only display if the mat-card-title has been clicked on. Sort of like a drop-down display that falls from the card title displaying the card content.

In other words, is there a way to only have the card content display after the title has been clicked?

Is there a way to achieve this without using mat-panel? The reason I want to do it this way is because mat-panel moves the entire screen when the panel opens.

Answer (score 1):

- There's already a easier & better way to do it. Its called [MatExpansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)
- In bootstrap terms its called `Accordion`.
- Here's a Angular component for that called [ngbAccordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples)

Comment: Could you take a look at this for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561454/opening-mat-expansion-panel-is-moving-the-opposite-column-how-to-keep-it-still